# Jquery vs PHP - load an image into a div

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a php script server side that load an image in a div on client side.

first shot:
ajax.php

```
if((isset($_POST['id'])) && ($_POST['id']=="loadphoto") && (ctype_digit($_POST['idp']))) {
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT articleid, photoid FROM articles_photos WHERE id='".$_POST['idp']."'", $mydb);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $path="./articles/photos/".$row[0]."/".$row[1];
        }

        echo $path;
    }
}
```

myjs.js

```
function loadPhoto(mexid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: './auth/ajax.php',
        data: 'idp='+escape(mexid)+'&id=loadphoto',
        success: function(msg) {
            $('.articleviewphoto1').find("img").each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass().addClass('photoarts');
            });

            $('#'+mexid).removeClass().addClass('photoartsb');
            $('#visualizator').html('<img src="'+msg+'" class="photoartb" />');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You mean the actual binary image code? Why? That has so many downsides and compatibility problems. Why not simply update an `<img>` element's `src` property?

Comment: As Pekka says, it seems much better to have ajax.php echo the image's src... or an anchor tag that includes an image tag with the image's src.

Comment: uhm yeah, the Pekka solution looks brillant. I can change the src propery, but i need to upload the img when the page is loaded to the client. How can do it? Load some div with the image and put them with css display:none; property?

Comment: anyway, i'm doing somethings like "watch photo" on facebook's album. I don't think is good, when you load a photo (so, a page with that photo) load others photo (just thinks to 5 photo 1 megabyte each...to load the page i need to wait long time) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to host a list of possible images in the PHP file and load different images based on the id you send?  If so, you can set:

```
$Img = $_POST['idp'];
```

And use a `switch` statement to pass back the image file path:

```
switch ($Img){
  case (some_value):
      echo 'images/some_file.jpg';
      break;

  case (another_value):
      echo 'images/another_file.jpg';
      break;

}
```

Then place the file path in an  tag and load that into `$('#visualizator').html();`

Am I on track at least with what you want?  If so, I can flesh the answer out a bit.

Comment: yeah! that's what i have to do. I have edited the post and put first example. what do you think about? tnx

Comment: Well, there are a few options and parameters in there that I don't know the reason for, but that's to be expected now having the entire project to look at...but it looks like it will work just fine.

Comment: I've a problem about this. I have the images as thumbs in a div (size max 100x100px trough a css rule) and the big photo in other div (size 700x700px trhough another css rule). the problem is that i load img (with size of 3-4mb, 2048x2112 for example), but with 5-6 photos with that size is too slow for the browser. The page is very slow. There is a solution? Maybe resize the image on server side when i upload them?

Comment: Try PhpThumb to resize the images on the fly.  I use this all the time and I like the easy of use.  here's an example:

`<img src="phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../images/FacStaff/snapshot-2.jpg&h=208&aoe=1" alt="Resized Image />`

Where 'h' sets the height and 'aoe' allows an image smaller than 208 to be enlarged.

http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Image-Galleries/phpThumb--2097.html

Comment: uhm, i found a manual about php GD. So i make the thumbs with the original photo ;) if it doesnt work, i try this! tnx man ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the image already exists somewhere and isn't being generated on the fly. In the PHP script, you can access the variables with `$_POST['idp']` and `$_POST['id']`. Do whatever processing you need, and then simply `echo` the URL. The variable `msg` in the javascript will be everything `echo`'d by the PHP script. Then, you could just do this:

```
$('#visualizator').html('<img src="' + msg + '" />');
```